# need help to accelerate creating pyomo model instance

Tags: matrix, constraints, pyomo, pypy

My pyomo spends almost 100% of its time creating the model instance. My code look like this:

```
import pyomo.environ as pyo
import materialAllocation_data_parsing
import cProfile as profile
import pstats

model = pyo.AbstractModel()

model.TH = pyo.Param(initialize=6) 
model.NF = pyo.Param(within=pyo.NonNegativeIntegers) 
model.NR = pyo.Param(within=pyo.NonNegativeIntegers) 

model.I = pyo.RangeSet(1, model.NR) 
model.J = pyo.RangeSet(1, model.NF) 
model.T = pyo.RangeSet(1, model.TH) 

model.R = pyo.Param(model.I, model.J, default = 0) 
model.PO = pyo.Param(model.I, model.T, default = 0) 
model.dFG = pyo.Param(model.J, model.T, default = 0) 
model.RM0 = pyo.Param(model.I, within=pyo.NonNegativeReals) 
model.FG0 = pyo.Param(model.J, within=pyo.NonNegativeReals) 
model.C = pyo.Param(model.J, within=pyo.NonNegativeReals) 
model.S = pyo.Param(model.J, within=pyo.NonNegativeReals) 

model.X = pyo.Var(model.T, model.J, domain=pyo.NonNegativeIntegers)

def obj_expression(m):
    return sum(m.S[j]*m.X[t,j] for t in m.T for j in m.J)

model.OBJ = pyo.Objective(rule=obj_expression, sense=pyo.maximize)

def rm_constraint_rule(m, i, t):
    rg= pyo.RangeSet(1,t)
    return m.RM0[i]+sum( -(m.X[t1, j] * m.R[i, j])  for j in m.J for t1 in rg) + sum(m.PO[i, t1] for t1 in rg)  >= 0

def fg_constraint_rule(m, j, t):
    rg = pyo.RangeSet(1,t)
    return m.FG0[j] + sum( - m.X[t1,j] + m.dFG[j,t1] for t1 in rg) >= 0

def cp_constraint_rule(m, j, t):
    return m.X[t,j] <= m.C[j]

model.rmConstraint = pyo.Constraint(model.I, model.T, 
rule=rm_constraint_rule)
model.fgConstraint = pyo.Constraint(model.J, model.T, 
rule=fg_constraint_rule)
model.cpConstraint = pyo.Constraint(model.J, model.T, 
rule=cp_constraint_rule)

data = data_parsing()


instance = model.create_instance(data, report_timing=True)

opt = pyo.SolverFactory('glpk')
```

Is there a way to accelerate the model instantiation? I assume most of the time is spent on creating these constraints. Can anybody help me to write these constraints in matrix form, if this is the way to accelerate the model instantiation ? Thanks!!

I tried pypy. It can accelerate a small problem from 10 minutes to 2 minutes. Still it is not enough to deal with a realistic problem.. meanwhile, pypy significantly slows down the data acquisition part, i.e., using pandas.

Comment: It really isn't possible to give you good advice without seeing more of the code.  Have you put in some timing marks?  `pandas` + data acquisition might be the bottleneck.  From the small piece of code you provided, the *very first* thing you should do is NOT make new `pyo.RangeSet`s inside of the functions.  Just make one in the main part of your model, name it, and re-use it.

Comment: Good idea...But t is an input of each constraint. is RangeSet(1,t) avoidable in the functions ?

Comment: i post all the codes here

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing really odd about the code and it still isn't clear from the details what is consuming time.  It could be the data handling, the model could be gigantic, or ???

Anyhow, you can take the first logical step and just use a regular python `range()` generator in your constraints instead of making new `pyo.RangeSet`s

I'd change this (and similarly for your other constraint):

```
def rm_constraint_rule(m, i, t):
    rg= pyo.RangeSet(1,t)
    return m.RM0[i]+sum( -(m.X[t1, j] * m.R[i, j])  for j in m.J for t1 in rg) + sum(m.PO[i, t1] for t1 in rg)  >= 0
```

To this:

def rm_constraint_rule(m, i, t):
return m.RM0[i]+sum( -(m.X[t1, j] * m.R[i, j])  for j in m.J for t1 in range(1, t+1) + sum(m.PO[i, t1] for t1 in range(1, t+1)  >= 0

Comment: In a small example, solving costs 0.15 seconds. Model instantiation costs 1.69 seconds. rm_costraint_rule costs 1.56 seconds. Is there a way to accelerate the nested sum ? meanwhile, R is actually very sparse. Can pyomo take advantage of the sparsity ?